# node.js sending a response from a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using the express framework to handle requests. Some of the steps involve invoking asynchronous functions. Eventually I would like the return the value computed in one of these functions.

```
app.post("/hello", function(req, res) {
    ...
    ...

    myFunc(finalFantasy);
}

function myFunc(callback) {
    ...
    callback();
}

function finalFantasy() {
    //I want to return this value in the response
    var result = "magic";
}
```

How can I use the value calculated in **finalFantasy** function in the response?

Comment: With the code structure identical to shown in the question, just make `myFunc` return the result of `callback` - and use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass the `res` instance to the callback, or use callback like the second example.

```
app.post("/hello", function(req, res) {
...
...

myFunc(finalFantasy, req, res);
}

function myFunc(callback, req, res) {
...
callback(req, res);
}

function finalFantasy(req, res) {
//I want to return this value in the response
var result = "magic";
res.end(result);
}
```

Another example is this:

```
app.post("/hello", function(req, res) {
    ...
    ...
    var i = 3;

    myFunc(i, function(data) {
        res.end(data); // send 4 to the browser
    });
}

function myFunc(data, callback) {
    data++; //increase data with 1, so 3 become 4 and call the callback with the new value
    callback(data); 
}
```

Comment: You should only do this for middleware, with passing the req/res to the wrapper myFunc and even worse to the finalFantasy you make them dependant on the req/res, no other code can use those methods without having the req/res objects

Comment: The second example is much better, there you give back control to the app.post callback, who has the origional req/res

Answer (score 2):

```
app.post("/hello", function(req, res) {
    ...
    ...

    var result = myFunc(finalFantasy);
}

function myFunc(callback) {
    ...
    return callback();
}

function finalFantasy() {
    //I want to return this value in the response
    var result = "magic";
    return result;
}
```

you almost had it, just like @raina77ow said in the comment, pass the result back up

Answer (score 1):

Keep passing `res` along, and in your final "response generating function", send data to it. The general way to do this with express is to use the middleware cascade, storing persistent values in res.locals:

```
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  // do things
  next();
},function(req, res, next) {
  // do more things
  next();
},function(req, res, next) {
  // do even more things!
  next();
},function(req,res) {
  // and finally we form a response
  res.write(things);
});
```

Although you normally put this in a middleware file and then include that, calling its functions:

```
// middleware "lib/functions.js" file
module.exports = {
  a: function(req, res, next) { ... },
  b: function(req, res, next) { ... },
  c: function(req, res, next) { ... }
}
```

and then in your app.js, main.js, or similarly obvious main file:

```
var mylib = require("./lib/functions");
...
app.get("/", mylib.a, mylib.b, mylib.c);
...
```

done. Nice and organised, and automatic passthrough of streams through the `next` concept.

Answer (score 1):

// wrap finalFantasy using an anonymous function

```
app.post("/hello", function(req, res) {
    ...
    ...
    myFunc(function () {
         var ret = finalFantasy();
         res.send(ret);
    });
}

function myFunc(callback) {
    ...
    callback();
}

function finalFantasy() {
    //I want to return this value in the response
    var result = "magic";
}
```